# Set Body Parameter in Angular HttpClient

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-core, rxjs

I have an Asp.Net Core Web API with Angular framework.

I have an action to get value as below:

```
    [HttpGet]

    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<MyModel>> Get([FromBody] MyParameter parameter) { ... }
```

And my client application is called API as follow:

```
return this.httpClient.get<MyModel[]>(`${environment.api}values`);
```

How I can set Body in API call?

Thanks

Comment: You can not set a body with a GET request. Use a POST one, or request parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to send body as param in `Get` request. Please use `POST`

**API**

```
[HttpPost]

public ActionResult<IEnumerable<MyModel>> Get([FromBody] MyParameter parameter) { ... }
```

**UI**

```
return this.httpClient.post<MyModel[]>(`${environment.api}values`);
```

If you want to user get, you can pass the params properties as `querystring`

Answer (score 1):

In HttpGet of Angular you can not set body you can only set the url and the http options like this

```js
getConfigResponse(): Observable<HttpResponse<Config>> {
  return this.http.get<Config>(
    this.configUrl, { observe: 'response' });
}
```

So if you want to submit the body you have to use post request like this

```js
return this.http.post<Hero>(this.heroesUrl, hero, httpOptions)
```